# DialgoFlow CX: check if not is is-listed

Tags: dialogflow-cx

[image: Example of pizza bot overruling my settings]

Hello,

I have all my intents is-listed. However, sometimes I don't want certain combinations to be happening and want to give an another answer.

Like in the picture, I don't want customers to allow to order anchovy and onions on a pizza. However, the customer was still able to order eventough I said to accept the onion but to not accept to anchovy...

How to prevent this to happen? I've tried ***!:*** but that didn't worked also...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a scenario in which you want to **restrict** certain combinations of options or inputs. If you are using a **natural language processing (NLP)** system for handling intents and responses, you might need to implement additional logic to handle such restrictions.

Here are a few potential workarounds you can consider:

- Implement custom validation logic in your code to check for disallowed combinations before processing the order. If the user's input contains a combination that should not be allowed (like anchovy and onions), you can reject the request or prompt the user to choose a different combination.
- Within your response generation logic, explicitly mention that certain combinations are not allowed. For example, if the user tries to order anchovy and onions together, your response can include a message like "I'm sorry, but we cannot process orders for pizzas with both anchovy and onions."
- When training your model, provide explicit negative examples where the model is trained not to accept certain combinations. Ensure that these examples are diverse and cover various disallowed combinations.

Without more details about the specific tools or platforms you are using, it's challenging to provide a more targeted solution.

Comment: Hello :)

Thank you very much for your answer. Basically in DialogFlow itself there is no option to restrict certain combinations without putting some other tooling in between to do so :)?